# How to create a N-dimentional feature vector in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, data-structures, feature-extraction

I have 20 pixel values for an image, and i would like to store them in a 20D feature vector, not a 20 length feature vector. I'm new to Python, so i don't know if in Python a regular array is considered a n-dimentional vector, or i need to vectorize a single array somehow. These are the pixels value:

```
[245, 247, 199, 199, 210, 213, 216, 196, 225, 
    199, 189, 189, 195, 221, 225, 201, 221, 201, 216, 222]
```

I wish to turn them into a 20d dimentional vector, how would i proceed to do that?

Comment: In your mind, what is the difference between a 20D feature vector and a 20-length one? Why not just use a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the shape of your solution array should be (20,1). To do this, np.reshape is the quickest and easiest way. The code to do this below:

```
np.reshape(your_array,(20,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. You could do it while keeping it as a list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

[[i] for i in l]
```

Or:

```
list(map(lambda x: [x], l))
```

Output:

```
Out[21]: [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```

Or use one of many ways to add a dimension to a `numpy` array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(l)
```

All of these are equivalent:

```
arr[Ellipsis, None]
```

```
np.expand_dims(arr, -1)
```

```
np.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5],
       [ 6],
       [ 7],
       [ 8],
       [ 9],
       [10]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process each value and then convert it into n-dimensional vector to get 20-D vectorised array.

```
def convertN(arr):
    #create n-dimensional arr
    #Return n-dimensional arr

input =[245,247,199...216,222]

for i,v in enumerate(input):
    input[i] = convertN(v)

print(input)
```